# Craft 3 / 4 CP: Restrict users to specific user groups in Users view

Tags: craft3, users, control-panel, permissions, user-groups

I need to restrict access to users **(not entries)** of say `AdminGroupA` to be able to access and manage users of `UserGroupA` in the Control Panel.  Right now, the user `AdminGroupA` can browse all of the users in Craft no matter what the permissions and user groups are.  As far as I can tell, there is no way to do that out of the box?

More details.  Say I have groups:

- `AdminGroupA`, `AdminGroupB`, `AdminGroupC`
- `UserGroupA`, `UserGroupB`, `UserGroupC`

I want to create an admin user (e.g. `AdminGroupA`) that only has access to a user group (e.g. `UserGroupA`).  I've given the group `AdminGroupA` the following permissions:

- Edit users

  - Register users
  - Moderate users
  - Assign user groups

    - Assign users to "`UserGroupA`"

This allows the user to browse all users in Craft no matter what the permissions and user groups are.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a more formal way to do it, but you could probably fake it with a combination of these free plugins...

- [Control Panel CSS](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-css)
- [Control Panel JS](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-js)
- [Control Panel Body Classes](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-body-classes)

** Disclaimer: I'm the author of all three.*